# SQL Query for Json Array where all numbers exist in list

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a column names `myNumbers` in SQL that is a string of json. The json is a list of ints. I want to query that table and only get back records where all ints in the json exist in a list I provide.

```
| myNumbers |
-------------
| [1, 2, 3] |
| [1, 2]    |
| [4, 5, 6] |
| [7, 8, 9] |
```

Example: I want all records that match numbers `(1, 2)`. I would only get back the second item (`[1, 2]`). If I wanted all records that matched numbers `(1, 2, 3)`, I would get back both `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2]`

What I want to do is this:

`select * from myTable where JSON_VALUE(myNumbers, '$') in (1, 2, 3)`

But that doesn't work out well. However, if I try the same approach but get the index instead, it works:

`select * from myTable where JSON_VALUE(myNumbers, '$[0]') in (1, 2, 3)`

I've tried a few other approaches with `openjson` and `json_query` but no luck.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of Relational Division, see [Joe Celko](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) et al.

You can solve this as follows:
Let us assume the required ints are passed through in a single column TVP (I would index it)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT [value]
    FROM OPEN_JSON(myNumbers, '$') WITH ([value] int '$')
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @tvp)
```

If you want to hard-code the numbers there is a simpler method:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT [value]
    FROM OPEN_JSON(myNumbers, '$') WITH ([value] int '$')
    WHERE [value] NOT IN (1,2,3))
```

We ask for all rows for which: there are no JSON ints which are *not* in the list, i.e. all of them are. If the size of the list is large, there may be faster ways to do this, but this is the most straightforward.

Comment: Is there any way to have a static list within the query instead of the `@tvp` setup?